# dtexec for linux, Argument for "set" is not valid

Tags: linux, ssis

I am trying to run an SSIS package on Linux and running into an issue trying to pass in a variable. The following command works fine on Windows with SQL 2017, but errors on linux:

```
dtexec /F Package4.dtsx /SET \Package.Variables[pDIR].Value;"C:\test\\"
```

The error on linux is:

```
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
Version 14.0.1000.169 for 64-bit
Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft. All rights reserved.

Argument ""Package.Variables[pDIR].Value"" for option "set" is not valid.
C:\test\: command not found
```

So the argument is invalid, and then the shell tries to execute the specified value as a command. Are parameters passed differently for the linux version?

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error I found the following to work:

```
dtexec /F Package5.dtsx /SET "\Package.Variables[pDIR].Value;"C:\\test\\""
```